# Use matrix modified by user in Shiny in R code

Tags: r, object, matrix, shiny

I would like to use a matrix whose values where modified by the users with Shiny in some subsequent R code. In other words, I would like to reintroduce the shiny input into my R code; the modified matrix as matrix object in my R code.

This is the code I use:

```
install.packages("shiny")
install.packages("shinyMatrix")
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

        n <- 10
        vnames <- as.character(1:n)
        
        m <- matrix(0, n, n, dimnames = list(vnames, vnames)) 
        
        ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("shinyMatrix: Simple App"),   
                        sidebarPanel(width = n+2,
                                     tags$h4("Data"),
                                     matrixInput("sample",
                                                 value = m,
                                                 rows = list(names = TRUE, editableNames = TRUE),
                                                 cols = list(names = TRUE, editableNames = TRUE))),
                        mainPanel(width = 6,
                                  tableOutput("matrix")))
        
        server <- function(input, output, session) {
          output$matrix <- renderTable({input$sample})
        }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I use the modified matrix as object in a subsequent R code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `input$sample` only updates when you click away from the editing matrix. When you do your `output$matrix` updates and you can just use `input$sample` as you would any other matrix in further R code in your shiny app.

Perhaps you have in mind a user editing the matrix, then shiny exiting and the matrix still being available afterwards? In that case you can just add the line `observeEvent(input$sample, {shiny_matrix <<- input$sample})` in your server function and a copy should be there when you exit the shiny app.

Comment: Thank you pseudospin, you described and solved my concern in your second paragraph. I guess there is no need to exit the app anymore if I introduce some reactive output functions? Thx!